# Decent lower bound on expected value

Tags: probability, expectation

Does anyone know a decent lower bound for the expected value of $E(\frac{x}{1+x})$ where $0<x<1$? Clearly $E(x/2)$ works, but I need something tighter. I want something in terms of $E(x)$ if possible. Using the inequality $\frac{x}{1+x} \geq x e^{-x}$ also didn't help, since I still need to take the expected value of that.

Comment: Can you compute anything from the CDF, e.g., $P(X\leq 0.5)$? Do you have any higher moments?

Comment: This is coming from a nonlinear problem. I can bound higher moments pretty easily with Jensen's inequality, since that thing cubed is convex. The PDF is unknown and I was looking to use expected values as a shortcut around a bunch of complicated stuff.

Comment: I was just thinking a simple polynomial might work, e.g., $0.82x-0.34x^2\le 1/1+x$ and the $\sup_{x \in (0,1)}|1/1+x - (0.82x-0.34x^2)|\leq 0.02.$ If you had a good way to compute $\mathbb{E}x^2$ that might be sufficient.

Comment: One possible lower bound, maybe is the AM-HM inequality: $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac {x} {1+x}dF_X(x) \geq \left(\int_0^1 \left(\frac {x} {1+x}\right)^{-1}dF_X(x)\right)^{-1} = \frac {1} {\displaystyle E\left[\frac {1} {X}\right]+1}$